# Interview available slot

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm currently doing recruitment system by using drupal 7..

In my system have 3 role..
1) applicant
2) hr admin
3) interviewer

Applicant can apply the job and HR admin will shortlisted the applicant. The interviewer can evaluate the shortlisted candidate during the interview session..

My question is there any module that can show the availability of the interview session..the idea is same like confrence session where we can register for the confrence and we can set the limit of audience.. Because i want the candidate can choose the interview session..

I've tried the signup module but i seem not working for drupal 7.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a simple sign up you are looking for, have you tried Entity Registration? https://www.drupal.org/project/registration. Works similar to Signup module

Comment: awesome dude..this is what i looking for..but does entity registration can show how many available slot in the form of calender? sorry im new to drupal..